# Can I draw a box in draw.io and paste an image inside it?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

For a text box, I draw a box and type text inside it.

How can an image box be drawn in `draw.io` i.e. draw a box and paste an image inside it?

Answer (score 1):

Just drag and drop the image from the filesystem to the diagram.